# Create custom exception with custom json response in spring boot api

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, exception

I would like to throw different exceptions with different Strings (giving details of the error via message) with a very specific JSON structure, something like:

```
   [
      {
        "error": [
          {
            "statusCode": 400,
            "customMessage": "xxx",
            "timestamp": "time"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Is this possible to achieve with Spring Boot? I haven't found how to do it.

Comment: You might be interested in my [error handling library](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/error-handling-spring-boot-starter). See https://foojay.io/today/better-error-handling-for-your-spring-boot-rest-apis/ for an introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ErrorHandler(as per your naming convention) class and extend spring class ResponseEntityExceptionHandler which receives all method exceptions. Check spring documentation for more details on this class.

In your class add handleTechincalException method as below for required exceptions.

```
@ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class, AbcException.class, XyzException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleTechnicalException(Exception e, WebRequest webRequest) {
// prepare response entity object as required based on type of exception 
// return ResponseEntity<Object>
}
```